# ¿Cómo evaluar preguntas en otro idioma con el nuevo sistema?

Tags: soporte, colas-de-revisión, revisión-de-pregunta

Hace unos minutos estaba revisando las primeras preguntas, pero me tocó una pregunta que estaba en inglés y las acciones que me ofrecían no eran acordes al problema.

[image: Idioma erróneo]

Al dejar un comentario me aparecen 2 opciones que no tienen nada que ver. Por el momento dejé un comentario sobre el idioma oficial, pero sigo sin terminar de acostumbrarme a este nuevo sistema. ¿Se equivocaron al momento de hacer el reporte?, ¿Es problema del sistema o de las traducciones?

**Si me vuelve a pasar esto, ¿Cómo debería actuar?, ¿Debería reportarla de nuevo pero en la categoría correcta?**

Comment: interesante.. hay que plantearlo en meta.se.... deberia haber mas motivos...supongo que poniendo que la pregunta no es clara, "se solucionaria".. pero no es el motivo real...

Comment: Publicado en meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369363/141717

Comment: @gbianchi, Gracias :)

Comment: Posiblemente lo mejor por ahora es reportar "La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español" y pasar sin tomar ninguna acción de la queue.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que hago en esos casos es primero reportarla con el botón **Reportar**.

Enseguida entro al reporte:

*Necesita mejoras > Una razón especifica de la comunidad > La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.*

Dejo el comentario de que la *pregunta no es clara* y habro la pregunta en otra pestaña del navegador o vuelvo a ella con el botón regresar y nuevamente dejo un comentario al OP para que traduzca su primera pregunta.

Es un proceso algo complejo, hechando en falta más opciones en los comentarios de las [nuevas colas de revisión](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/436501)

P.D. Entre las acciones de "Se ve bien", "Editar" y "Dejar un comentario" haría falta otra opción para reportar y continuar con el proceso sin salir de la pantalla.